# How to make bootstrap col-sm-* work in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project which is responsive till `col-sm` . I need that to render perfect in mobile device.
As whole project is already build up it's almost impossible for me to add `col-xs-*` for mobile.
Is there any `jquery/scss` way to make `col-sm` work as `col-xs` on mobile.

I need tablet version to open in mobile devices

Answer (score 2):

Since `col-sm` classes (specifically widths) kick in from 768px, you can OVERRIDE Bootstrap's styling for `col-sm`'s to mimick `col-xs` behaivour for  lower viewports. The first thing to ensure is that you have a parent class in your project that you can use as a parent / child selector as simply writing styles like `.col-sm-* {}` will conflict with Bootstrap's native styling.

Let's say your body tag has a class of "`page`" for example, we can use `@media` queries to mimick what the col-xs classes do below 767px:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .page .col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .page .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .page .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

You can also use wildcards the same way Bootstrap does too:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .page div[class^="col-sm-"] {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Also, ensure your custom CSS file is referenced AFTER the Bootstrap one.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do multiple col sizes in your code, too.

```
`<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>`
```

Here's the link for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Thanks, I know about this. But my project is already built.I just need a css or jquery code to change default behavior of `col-sm` so that it start working on mobile as well.